# Почему не происходит сложение массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
var a = [2, 1];
var b = [9, 5];

function mergeArray(a, b) {
  var array = a.concat(b);
  document.write(array);
}

mergeArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

При вызове функции вы не передаете в нее параметры, поэтому внутри функции `mergeArray` переменные `a` и `b` имеют значение `undefined`

Что бы все заработало функцию надо вызвать вот так

```
mergeArray(a, b);
```

```js
var a = [2, 1];
var b = [9, 5];

function mergeArray(a, b) {
  var array = a.concat(b);
  document.write(array);
}

mergeArray(a, b);
```

Comment: а как сделать так чтобы не затирать область видимости глобальных и локальных переменных?

Comment: глобальные переменные - это плохой стиль и источник проблем. если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, то отметьте его как принятый - это поможет другим.

Comment: Как бы вы сами здесь написали?

Comment: так как я написал это в ответе

Comment: я имею ввиду как предать в параметры a и b в функцию, но при этом не делать глобальную и локальную переменную идентичными?

Comment: это не форум. это сайт вопросов и ответов. задайте отдельный вопрос и вам ответят. это поможет не только вам, но и другим людям. комментарии обычно удаляют и не читают.